# Slick 3 use custom MappedColumnType in custom SourceCodeGenerator

Tags: scala, code-generation, slick, slick-3.0

I have this customized source code generator using the default `PostgresProfile` and I want it to generate `java.time.OffsetDateTime` columns when dealing with `java.sql.Timestamp` types. I've come as far as using the rawType but I don't understand what I'm supposed to override to be able to use the imported implicit mappers.

When I run the codegen task, it imports `SlickColumnMappers` but that's as far as it goes. The generated columns continue to be `java.sql.Timestamp`.

This has been a major blocker for me. Help is greatly appreciated.

**Mapper**

```
object SlickColumnMappers {
  implicit val TimestampToOffsetDateTime = MappedColumnType.base[OffsetDateTime, Timestamp](
    dt => Timestamp.from(dt.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant),
    ts => OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(ts.toInstant, ZoneOffset.UTC)
  )
}
```

**Source Code Generator**

```
new SourceCodeGenerator(model) {
  override def Table = new Table(_) {
    override def code: Seq[String] = Seq(
      "import helpers.SlickColumnMappers._"
    ) ++ super.code

    override def Column = new Column(_) {
      override def defaultCode = v => {
        def raw(v: Any) = rawType match {
          case "String" => "\"" + v + "\""
          case "Long" => v + "L"
          case "Float" => v + "F"
          case "Char" => "'" + v + "'"
          case "scala.math.BigDecimal" => s"scala.math.BigDecimal($v)"
          case "Byte" | "Short" | "Int" | "Double" | "Boolean" => v.toString
        }
        v match {
          case Some(x) => s"Some(${raw(x)})"
          case None => "None"
          case x => raw(x)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column mappings allow you to use custom classes in your Row models, but will not affect code generation. In order to change code generation you need to override the `Table` method inside `SourceCodeGenerator`

```
  override def Table = new Table(_) {


    override def Column = new Column(_){
      override def rawType = {
        val superRawType = super.rawType
        superRawType match {
          case "java.sql.Timestamp" => "java.time.ZonedDateTime"
          case "java.sql.Date" => "java.time.LocalDate"
          case x => x
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: It works, but what's the difference of `Column.rawType` from `Column.defaultCode`?

Comment: It is explained by the comments in the code in slick.codegen: RawType returns the type of the column, defaultCode wrap any value into its type

Comment: Just a clarification: since I'm dealing with datetimes with timezone, will the implicit mapping modify both datetimes to UTC timezone, or do I still have to override another method to make sure the mapping always normalizes the OffsetDateTime objects to UTC before being translated back to sql.Timestamp? I worry that the conversion by Slick from `OffsetDateTime` to `sql.Timestamp` for altering the db does not convert the OffsetDateTime object to UTC before alteration. So, if I have `.....+0800`, will it be converted to its equivalent `+0800 Timestamp` or to an adjusted `UTC Timestamp`?